# Installing mathjax breaks terminal prompt (and sublime text)

Tags: sublimetext3, mathjax, archlinux, terminator

Recently, I installed the arch community package "mathjax" to be able to render some mathematical formulas in a jupyter notebook.
It works for the notebooks, but after the installation, other things are broken, like the rendering of
special symbols in Terminator and Sublime Text 3.

Here is the symbol in question, displayed in Sublime and in the actual prompt in Terminator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vD2c.jpg

My question is, how can I keep mathjax from changing these things.
How can this even happen? I thought the package is just relevant to
in-browser Latex rendering.

Comment: versions are:
community/mathjax 2.7.0-2, community/terminator 1.91-5, Sublime Text Build 3126

Comment: Random guess: try temporarily removing the fonts installed with MathJax.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I tried renaming the /usr/share/fonts/mathjax and /usr/share/mathjax directories, is that enough? This has no effect on the problem described above

Comment: Sorry, that's the only thing I could imagine. Maybe it is not dependent on MathJax?

Comment: Removing the /usr/share/fonts/mathjax folder completely works.
But the problem persists after I copy it back in there.

Comment: Interesting. The problem must be that MathJax fonts are used. The folder must have been added to the font lookup paths which is not advisable for these fonts in general anyway; might be considered a bug in the arch package

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a really bad solution to this is to move the mathjax folder in /usr/share/fonts to a new location and link to this location in the /usr/share/mathjax folder, overwriting the previous link named "fonts".

This fixes the issues with special symbols in Terminator and Sublime.
At least for Jupyter Notebooks, this does not seem to be breaking the rendering of formulas.

This is just a temporary solution, so I hope someone can find a better one.